# Static variable value is not changing in mapper function

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, iteration

I am trying to write iterative mapreduce for BFS graph algorithm
In order to specify when to stop the iteration,I am trying to use the counter

The code is

```
public class GraphSearch extends Configured implements Tool {

static int counter=0;


public static class MapClass extends MapReduceBase implements
Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> {

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<IntWritable, Text> output,
            Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

        Node node = new Node(value.toString()) ;




        if (node.getColor() == Node.Color.GRAY) {
            if(node.getDistance()==Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                node.setDistance(0);


            for (int v : node.getEdges()) {

                Node vnode = new Node(v);


                    vnode.setDistance(node.getDistance() + 1);
                    vnode.setColor(Node.Color.GRAY);
                    output.collect(new IntWritable(vnode.getId()), vnode.getLine());

            }

            node.setColor(Node.Color.BLACK);
            setCounter(1);



        }


        output.collect(new IntWritable(node.getId()), node.getLine());

    }

    static void setCounter(int i) {
        if(i==1)
        counter=counter+1;
        else
        counter=0;

    }
```

The idea is when the counter remains 0,that means all the nodes are traversed(All have become black-colored) and BFS is completed

```
private boolean checkForConvergence(int iteration_number){
    if(counter!=0&&iteration_number!=0){
        return true;
    }
     return false
   }
```

But setCounter is not showing any changes on the counter value .
What to do?
Is there any other way of having global variable in Java(like in c++ ,it is pretty simple--just declare to it outside everything)??

Comment: Mapreduce has a separate concept of counters, but you have to set them within the `Context` variable (assuming you were using non-deprecated MapReduce2 API)

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you are doing, but anyway: you declare `static` counter variable in `GraphSearch` class which is a hadoop job class. Hadoop job is run on a hadoop node in its own JVM. Mappers in hadoop run in separate JVM and have their own instance of this variable. That's the reason your code does not work.

I have no idea how your algorithm should work so I do not suggest any changes. Start with Hadoop [tutorials](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/hello-world-an-introduction-to-hadoop-hcatalog-hive-and-pig/#section_2) to understand the idea of map reduce algorithms.